# How to aggregate sub-regions Covid cases into larger regions in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have a dataset containing new covid cases per day by 16 German regions. I want to aggregate the number of cases per day in three regions (that don't exist in the dataset, i would have to create them and they each one would be composed of the sum of daily cases of certain subregions). How can i accomplish this on SQL. The data is from https://npgeo-corona-npgeo-de.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/dd4580c810204019a7b8eb3e0b329dd6_0/explore
And is divided by smaller provinces and sex, i already aggregated it by the 16 regions of germany that are in the dataset with the following query:

```
SELECT date, Bundesland, SUM(AnzahlFall) AS total_cases FROM RKI_COVID19
GROUP BY date, Bundesland
ORDER BY date, Bundesland ASC;
```

Like i said i want to aggregate it in three larger regions (north, center, south) each one of them contain some of the 16 regions.

Comment: What do you mean "three regions . . . that don't exist in the dataset"?  How are you going to get data that is not in the table?  Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Sorry i mean three regions that are not defined yet, the data of this regions would be the sum of daily cases for some of the subregions (Example: region 1 would be the sum of berlin bavaria and other). I would have to define what subregions compose the three bigger ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to combine regions into "super regions".  As generic SQL, you can use:

```
SELECT date, super_region, SUM(total_cases)
FROM (SELECT date, Bundesland, SUM(AnzahlFall) AS total_cases,
             (CASE Bundesland
                   WHEN 'Schleswig-Holstein' THEN 'Region1'
                   WHEN . . .
              END) as super_region
      FROM RKI_COVID19
      GROUP BY date, Bundesland
     ) c
GROUP BY date, super_region
ORDER BY date, super_region ASC;
```